# accessing values of table in c# using values from other table

Tags: c#, sql

I have two tables named myfriends and imageslikes . In my code I am trying to access a column  id2 of table myfriends and based on **each value** in that column I want to access records of imageslikes table. But with my code I am getting only value as output of repeater may be beacause its getting overwritten.

What could be the possible solution for accessing all the records i want to? can someone help?

```
        Query = "select id2 from myfriends where id1 = '" + Session["id"] + "'";
        adap = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, con);
        ds = new DataSet();
        adap.Fill(ds);
        dt = ds.Tables[0];
        dr = dt.Rows[0];
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            string id2 = row["id2"].ToString();
            Query = "select * from imageslikes where likedby = '" + id2 + "'";
            adap = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, con);
            ds = new DataSet();
            adap.Fill(ds);
            DataList4.DataSource = ds;
            DataList4.DataBind();



        }
```

Comment: I may be blind but I'm failing to see why you're defining the exact same query twice and filling the exact same data adapter twice with it...?

Comment: yes i was doing that but i was binding the data first in datalist and then in some other repeater.. I think thats not the problem .. by the way .. i have edited for "your" convenience.

Comment: try using INNER JOIN. INNER JOIN selects all rows from both tables as long as there is a match between the columns in both tables.

Comment: Well, for my convenience and anyone else in future who wants to search for an answer to a similar issue, which is the point of StackOverflow :)

Comment: thank you for being so friendly mr.intracept..

Comment: You're welcome, but don't assume that I'm male ;)

Comment: They have invented relation databases so that you can get the results using a single DB call. @user3608397 has your query down below. Better yet - put the query inside a stored proc and call that proc by name.

Answer (score 1):

```
        Query = "select * from imageslikes where likedby=(select id2 from myfriends where id1 = '" + Session["id"] + "') ";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Query = "select id2 from myfriends where id1 = '" + Session["id"] + "'";
adap = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, con);
ds = new DataSet();
adap.Fill(ds);
dt = ds.Tables[0];
dr = dt.Rows[0];
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string id2 = row["id2"].ToString();
    Query = "select * from imageslikes where likedby = '" + id2 + "'";
    adap = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, con);
    ds = new DataSet();
    adap.Fill(ds);
    DataList4.DataSource = ds;
    DataList4.DataBind();

    //Added this line
    ds = new DataSet();
    //if you need both records related to id1 and id2 then use
    Query = "select * from imageslikes where likedby in ('" + id2 + "', '" + id1 + "')";

    //Query = "select * from imageslikes where likedby = '" + id2 + "'";
    adap = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, con);
    ds = new DataSet();
    adap.Fill(ds);
    Repeater3.DataSource = ds;
    Repeater3.DataBind(); 


}
```